# How to conditionally import data from excel to fillable PDF using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, excel, pdf, fillable

I have created a fillable PDF form & now I need to import data from an excel sheet based on the selection of two different combo boxes. To be more specific, one combo box contains job category and other contains job level. Based on these selections the respective employee's salary amount and allowance amount should be imported into fillable PDF's text field for calculation from an excel sheet. Can someone shed some light to get an idea from where to start? I am a beginner in fillable PDF related javascript & I have very basic level of knowledge in this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments K J. What I'm trying to do here is, automatically populate textbox of PDF fillable form with data from excel, using JavaScript, when user select certain option from a combo box within the same form. Does this make any sense to you? Sorry for my bad description.

Comment: I understand. My intention is to look into possibilities before jump into coding. According to your last comment it is more of a heavy programming with 3rd party APIs, rather than a simple PDF JavaScript... Thanks for your feedback KJ.